# Combing multiple SELECT SQL Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am fairly new to SQL programming and I am trying to combine two queries into one. I have tried multiple times to combine the two, but am coming up short due to syntax issues. Here are the two queries I have:

```
SELECT 
    MIN([NewQuery]![TotalBasePay-Amount]) AS 75P
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 25 PERCENT [TotalBasePay-Amount] 
     FROM NewQuery  
     WHERE RTRIM([TotalBasePay-Amount]) <> '' 
     ORDER BY [TotalBasePay-Amount] DESC)  AS Subquery;
```

And the other:

```
SELECT 
    MIN([NewQuery]![TotalBasePay-Amount]) AS 90P
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [TotalBasePay-Amount] 
     FROM NewQuery 
     WHERE RTRIM([TotalBasePay-Amount]) <> ' ' 
     ORDER BY [TotalBasePay-Amount] DESC)  AS Subquery;
```

Can anyone assist/explain the most effective way to combine these two queries into one?

I appreciate it.

Comment: You can look up `union`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine using UNION ALL for all records, UNION for distinct records between the two tables:

eg:

```
Select something, somethingelse, 'your label1'
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT something, somethingelse, 'your label2'
FROM table2
```

Comment: Thanks. That displayed the results by row. Is there anyway to add a label to each row in a separate column?

Comment: Just added it to the query